# Firebase Storage 403 Error on delete

Tags: firebase, firebase-security, firebase-storage

I'm using the following rules:

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/xxxxxxx.appspot.com/o {
match /proUsers/{userId}/{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == userId && request.resource.size < 2 * 1024 * 1024 && request.resource.contentType.matches('image/.*'); 
    }
  }
}
```

This is how I'm creating the ref for saving:

```
storageRef.child(`proUsers/${userId}/${prizeData.title}_${prizeData.createdAtTimeStamp}`).put(file, metadata)
```

Attempting to delete it I'm creating this Ref:

```
  const prizeImageRef = storageRef.child(`proUsers/${userId}/${prizeData.title}_${prizeData.createdAtTimeStamp}`)
  return prizeImageRef.delete()
```

I keep getting the 403 error:

> code : "storage/unauthorized"
>
> Firebase Storage: User does not have permission to access

Are my rules for deletion not correct?

Comment: someone else already solved it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922124

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, I think the main issue here is that `request.resource.contentType.matches('image/.*')` is going to be null because you won't get the contentType on `DELETE`.